# ICU binaries seem incomplete when building from source

Tags: unicode, icu

I'm trying to build ICU 72 for Windows. I got the [source](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-72-1/icu4c-72_1-src.zip) (ICU4C) from the GitHub repo and built the project with Visual Studio 2019 by following the steps outlined on the [ICU website](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu4c/build.html#how-to-build-and-install-on-windows). I also ran the tests as specified on the website, and all of them pass.

However, when I check the content of icu/bin, the .dll files are suspiciously tiny. In particular, icudt72.dll is only 3KB whereas its counterpart in [the binary distribution](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-72-1/icu4c-72_1-Win64-MSVC2019.zip) is over 30MB.

This is an issue for me as I am trying to call icu::Normalizer2::getNFKCInstance() in my code but am getting U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR. I suspect that this could be due to one of the ICU .dlls being incomplete and not including the normalizer.

I cannot simply use the ICU binaries distributed on the ICU GitHub as I am building with custom build settings. I thought that the small .dll file were because of my build settings, but it turns out that a fresh (unmodified) copy of the source builds into those tiny .dlls as well.

I imagine that there's something in the process I missed, but I can't figure out what. Can anyone lend me a hand? Thanks!!